# SQLite ignore None on INSERT

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using an API that returns different dicts depending on the query. So because I can't be certain I'll have the desired keys, I'm using `dict.get()` to avoid raising a `KeyError`. But I am currently inserting these results into a database, and would like to avoid filling rows with `None`.

What would be the preferred way to deal with this?

Comment: What do you want it to be filled with? You can supply second argument to `.get()` function, which will return your second argument if key's not found. like this `dct.get('key', 'default')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NULL` as default value with `dict.get()`. In case `key` is not present in your `dict` object, it will return `NULL` instead of `None`. 'NULL' in databases (most) is equivalent to `None` in Python. For example:

```
>>> my_dict = {}

#                         v  Returns `NULL` if key not found in `my_dict`
>>> my_dict.get('key', 'NULL')
'NULL'
```

In case, you have column as `NOT NULL`, set them as empty string. For example:

```
>>> my_dict.get('key', '')
''
```

Comment: There are a few columns in the database that are `NOT NULL`. What then?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe: Check the update code. In that case you may set it as empty string